# Interpreting the Trussell Family Tree

Tags: family-tree, pedigree

I am having trouble interpreting [a family tree of the Trussell family](http://hankeringforhistory.com/billesley-manor-and-the-trussells/) that I found:

[image: http://hankeringforhistory.com/wp-content/uploads/trussellgen.jpg]

Specifically, near the top right, I see: "WILLIAM = ROHESE dau[ghter] and heir of WILLIAM PANTULF of Cublesdon Staffs: Justice of the Common Pleas 1268".  A line goes down and left to "MAUD" in "WILLIAM = MAUD dau[ghter] and heir of WARIN MANWARING of WIRMINGHAM CHES".  The line makes it look as though the first WILLIAM and ROHESE are the parents of MAUD, but the text makes me think MAUD's father is WARIN MANWARING.  What is the most likely interpretation?

Comment: I'm new to this SE site, so I'd welcome feedback on asking better questions (including good titles).  Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH.SE!  There are some tips on asking good questions in the [help], and if you'd like to talk about how to write better ones, feel free to ask on [Meta].  I'm still struggling on how to write a good title myself.  Glad to have you with us!

Comment: I am a publishing biographer of the de Vere earls of Oxford, I can help you with some members of the Trussell family who married into the de veres.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maud's father is Warin Mainwaring.

The tree is following the male line of descent otherwise known as patrilineal descent, so the lines go from father to son. The only exception to this is when there is no male heir.

Comment: So it's irrelevant that the line drops down onto MAUD?

Comment: @espertus: Yes, irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

The Trussell family tree correctly splits the two main lines of medieval Trussells, that helpfully bore different heraldic coats, but it is incomplete.  For example the William Trussell who married Maud Mainwaring had 3 sons, John, William and Warin(Warren)see Dugdale Antiquities of Warwickshire p537. The tree only shows 2.
Maidenhead Civic Society has published a booklet entitled "The Genealogy of the Trussell Family from C13th to C15th/16th" to elucidate the careers of the many Sir William Trussells and also to record the various churches around England where Trussell armorial glass is extant or used to occur.  For more information contact www.maidenheadcivicsoc.org.uk